# Put Rally.ui.chart.Chart charts inside a container

Tags: javascript, highcharts, rally

I'm trying to put two Rally charts inside a container to have a control over their layout. Unfortunately, for some reason, it doesn't work.
Plase see the code (the full HTML provided for convinience):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://rally1.rallydev.com/apps/2.0rc3/sdk.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    Rally.onReady(function () {
            Ext.define('CustomApp', {
extend: 'Rally.app.App',
componentCls: 'app',

_atTheStartAddedChart: null,
_stateChart: null,

launch: function () {
    //Write app code here
    var me = this;

    me._createAtTheStartAddedChart();
    me._createStateChart();

    console.log('chart 1', me._atTheStartAddedChart);
    console.log('chart 2', me._stateChart);

    me._chartContainer = Ext.create('Ext.Container', {
        itemId: 'cont',
        renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
        layout: {
            type: 'hbox',
            align: 'middle'
        }
        ,
        items: [
            me._atTheStartAddedChart,
            me._stateChart
        ]
    });
    me.add(me._chartContainer);
},

_createAtTheStartAddedChart: function () {
    var me = this;

    var series = [
        {
            type: 'pie',
            name: 'Features',
            data: [
                {
                    name: 'At the Start',
                    y: 20,
                    color: '#0CDBE8'
                },
                {
                    name: 'Added During Release',
                    y: 30,
                    color: '#FFE11A'
                }
            ]
        }
    ];

    var chart = me._createChart(series);
    me._atTheStartAddedChart = chart;
},

_createStateChart: function () {
    var me = this;

    var series = [
        {
            type: 'pie',
            name: 'Features',
            data: [
                {
                    name: 'Not Completed in Time',
                    y: 10,
                    color: '#FFE11A'
                },
                {
                    name: 'Completed in Time',
                    y: 15,
                    color: '#98C000'
                },
                {
                    name: 'Removed from Release',
                    y: 20,
                    color: '#EA2E49'
                },
                {
                    name: 'Completely Removed',
                    y: 5,
                    color: '#3D4C53'
                }
            ]
        }
    ];

    var chart = me._createChart(series);
    me._stateChart = chart;
},

_createChart: function (series) {
    var chart = Ext.create('Rally.ui.chart.Chart', {
        chartConfig: {
            chart: {
                plotBackgroundColor: null,
                plotBorderWidth: null,
                plotShadow: false
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Release Features'
            },
            tooltip: {
                pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.y}</b>'
            },
            plotOptions: {
                pie: {
                    allowPointSelect: false,
                    cursor: 'pointer',
                    dataLabels: {
                        enabled: false
                    },
                    showInLegend: true
                }
            }
        },
        chartData: {
            series: series
        }
    });

    return chart;
}
});


        Rally.launchApp('CustomApp', {
            name:"Random App Name42726",
            parentRepos:""
        });

    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

The charts are created successfully, but they are not displayed at all. There is no error related to their display, so I don't even know where to look for the issue.
Maybe someone knows how to put the charts horizontally (I don't really need Ext.Container here, any other container will be fine as well)?

There is also an error Uncaught Highcharts error #16: www.highcharts.com/errors/16 (Highcharts already defined in the page), not sure what's the reason for it as well.

Comment: Error 16 means that you have attached highcharts.js a few times.

Comment: Yes, but the thing is I'm not using Highcharts directly, I use Rally wrapper, so I don't load highcharts.js myself.

Comment: An interesting thing is that if I add a timeout, like a second between creating the charts, the Error 16 stops to appear. For me, it looks like Rally wrapper is adding highcharts.js somewhere inside and doesn't handle it properly for two caharts added immediately one after another.

Comment: Honestly Im not familiar with ruby wrappers, so I guess that you need to contact with wrapper authors.

Comment: Yeah, they recommend to ask question on SO, and in case I don't get the answer, I'll contact the support:). Thanks for looking into the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made those charts display - you may see full app and the screenshot showing both pie charts in [this repo](https://github.com/nmusaelian-rally/two-pie-charts).

Here is the js file. The main change was where in the code the chart was added to container. I moved that to `_createChart` function. Highchart error 16 does not prevent the charts from loading. You may eventually create two containers and add the charts to separate containers, but this works in its simplest form:

```
Ext.define('CustomApp', {
    extend: 'Rally.app.App',
    componentCls: 'app',
    _atTheStartAddedChart: null,
    _stateChart: null,
    items: [
        {
            xtype: 'container',
            itemId: 'mychart',
            columnWidth: 1
        }
    ],
    launch: function() {

        this._createAtTheStartAddedChart();
        this._createStateChart();
    },

    _createAtTheStartAddedChart: function () {

    var series = [
        {
            type: 'pie',
            name: 'Features',
            data: [
                {
                    name: 'At the Start',
                    y: 20,
                    color: '#0CDBE8'
                },
                {
                    name: 'Added During Release',
                    y: 30,
                    color: '#FFE11A'
                }
            ]
        }
    ];
    this._createChart(series);
},

    _createStateChart: function () {
        var me = this;

        var series = [
            {
                type: 'pie',
                name: 'Features',
                data: [
                    {
                        name: 'Not Completed in Time',
                        y: 10,
                        color: '#FFE11A'
                    },
                    {
                        name: 'Completed in Time',
                        y: 15,
                        color: '#98C000'
                    },
                    {
                        name: 'Removed from Release',
                        y: 20,
                        color: '#EA2E49'
                    },
                    {
                        name: 'Completely Removed',
                        y: 5,
                        color: '#3D4C53'
                    }
                ]
            }
        ];
        this._createChart(series);
},

    _createChart: function (series) {
        var chartDiv = this.down("#mychart");
        chartDiv.add({
            xtype: 'rallychart',
            chartConfig: {
                chart: {
                    plotBackgroundColor: null,
                    plotBorderWidth: null,
                    plotShadow: false
                },
                title: {
                    text: 'Release Features'
                },
                tooltip: {
                    pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.y}</b>'
                },
                plotOptions: {
                    pie: {
                        allowPointSelect: false,
                        cursor: 'pointer',
                        dataLabels: {
                            enabled: false
                        },
                        showInLegend: true
                    }
                }
            },
            chartData: {
                series: series
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but if I change the container layout, the charts stop showing. And by default, they are still displayed vertically and not horizontally. To check it, just add layout property to the container: `items: [
        {
         xtype: 'container',
         itemId: 'mychart',
         columnWidth: 1,
         layout: {
          type: 'hbox'
         }
        }
 ]`

Comment: Also tried the solution with adding two separate containers for each charts and then adding those containers to one main container. Again, if I don't specify layout for the main container, everything works, but if I try to show the two child containers horizonatally, charts are not displayed.

Comment: When I use two child containers and add a chart per container that works, but when I add a layout as a string or as an object the charts do not show exactly as you observed. I submitted a bug.

Comment: Thank you! Do you have any estimations about the expected fix date?

Comment: I'll accept the answer as it should work when the fix is rolled out.